# Identify $E$ where $E=\{a\in \Bbb R:\lim a^nA^n$ exists and is different from zero$\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

> Let $A=$ \begin{bmatrix} 3 &1\\ 2&  4\end{bmatrix}
>
> Let $E=\{a\in \Bbb R:\lim a^nA^n$ exists and is different from zero$\}$
>
> Identify $E$.

**ATTEMPT**:

The eigen values of $A$ are $5,2$ and since they are distinct the matrix is diagonalizable.
Hence $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D=$\begin{bmatrix} 5 &0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}

So $A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$ where  $D^n=$$$\begin{bmatrix} 5^n &0\\0&2^n\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now $a^nA^n=a^n(PD^nP^{-1})=P(a^nD^n)P^{-1}=$ $$P\begin{bmatrix} a^n5^n&0\\0&a^n2^n\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$$

We know that $r^n$ converges to $0$ only when $|r|<1 $ and converges to $1$ if $r=1$ ,for other values of $r$ the series diverges or oscillates

We have $5^n|a|^n$ converges to $0$ when $|a|<\frac{1}{5}$ and so does $2^n|a|^n$.

But if $|a|<\frac{1}{5}$ $\lim a^nA^n\to 0$ hence we have
$a=\frac{1}{5}$.

If $ |a|<\frac{1}{5}$ then $a^nA^n\to 0$

Hence $A=\{ \frac{1}{5}\}$.

This problem appeared in an exam a year ago.Is my solution correct?
Where can I improve the solution?Will I get full marks?
Please help.

Comment: How can you have "$|a|<1/5$ and $a=1/5$"?

Comment: This seems fine, except for a few typos. I think "$|a|<1/5$ and $a=1/5$" should be "... or ...". Also "$A=\{1/5\}$" should be "$E=\{1/5\}$". And the expression for $D^n$ is missing exponents.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown;i have fixed some issues;can you check now

Comment: @stewbasic; done; is it okay now?